# How to set the global variable in a function for cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a CMakeLists.txt to generate files and compile the generated files. I create a function to add some file path strings to a global list variable.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(source_list "nothing")
function(test file_path)
    list(APPEND source_list ${file_path})
endfunction(test)
test(abc.txt)
test(def.txt)
message("At last, the source_list is:\"${source_list}\"")
```

The cmake output:

```
At last, the source_list is:"nothing"
```

Someone suggested that to use macro instead of function, but I do need use local variable, so I need to use the function instead of macro.

How can I correctly set the global variable source_list in the function test()? Can't cmake do it in a simple and normal way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `set` instead of `list` to affect the variable in the parent scope.

So replace your `list` command with:

```
set(source_list ${source_list} ${file_path} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Comment: It's not global though, siblings will not see.

Comment: @JoachimW: Why incorporate two answers into the single one? You seems to misunderstand Question/Answer model on Stack Overflow. We do NOT tend to have **all solutions** in the **single accepted answer**. Instead, having **one answer per solution** is perfect. And an answer's quality is primarily measured by the **voting**, good answers needn't to be marked with the green accept mark. Please, revert this answers merging.

Answer (score 46):

PARENT_SCOPE is only for parent, it won't work if you have other non-parent script that want to see it as well.

You need cache for the true "global-like" variable. In your case, use:

```
SET(source_list  "${source_list}" CACHE INTERNAL "source_list")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for second run of cmake, because value is already in cache. You must clean before build.

Comment: `INTERNAL` implied `FORCE`, which means:
Use the ``FORCE`` option to
overwrite existing entries.

Answer (score 27):

Another approach is to use global properties. Once you set it:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list_property "${source_list}")
```

you can read it from everywhere:

```
get_property(source_list GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list_property)
```

I used in examples above the different names for property (`source_list_property`) and for variable (`source_list`). Maybe it is better to use the same name. But point is to use a property as global variables, and not about naming.

Such global properties aren't in cache.

Answer (score 11):

Building upon Maxim Suslov's answer, the following code worked for a similar problem I faced:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list)
function(add_source)
    get_property(tmp GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list)
    foreach(arg ${ARGV})
        set(tmp "${tmp} ${arg}")
    endforeach()
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list "${tmp}")
endfunction(add_source)

add_source(a_file)
add_source(b_file c_file)

get_property(local_prop GLOBAL PROPERTY source_list)
message("list: ${local_prop}")
```

Function add_source can be called from inside any sub-directory.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to address this issue is using `macro` instead of `function` - this way all variables inside macro will be evaluated in context of caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with environment variables.

```
  SET(ENV{SOURCE_LIST} "$ENV{SOURCE_LIST} newSource")
```

Test:

```
  message(STATUS "GLOBAL: $ENV{SOURCE_LIST}")
  -- GLOBAL: newSource /unittest/demo1 /unittest/demo2
```