# How to call a CMake function from add_custom_target/command?

Tags: c++, cmake, target, cmake-custom-command

Is it possible to call a CMake function out of an `add_custom_target` or `add_custom_command`?

I know I could move the CMake function to a Python (or whatever) script and call it from `add_custom_target`/`command` but I would like to avoid having tons of script next to the existing CMake infra.

What I want to achieve is to use CPack for generating a zip package of binary artifacts and publish them in an artifact repository. For the publishing part I have already the CMake function created but now I need to combine the packaging and publishing together.

Thanks for any help/hints in advance.

Comment: I looked for the same and after a few minutes i realized that this is impossible because cmake is a build-generator generator. This command will just be run at a different time, for example from within your IDE, when the cmake is just not existing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I encountered this issue while writing a CMake build system for [BVLC/Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe). What I finally did is I put the function content into a separate CMake script and called it from within `add_custom_target` by invoking:

```
add_custom_target(target_name
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P path_to_script
)
```

Invoking CMake with `-P` flag makes it act as a scripting language. You can put any CMake functions inside the script.

Comment: It boggles my mind that you cannot call cmake commands like FILE directly from within add_custom_command

Comment: Looks interesting, are parent CMake file definitions retained?

Comment: Actually, I found out that it doesn't BUT you can add a bunch of -D switched to 'forward' existing definitions to the child CMake script:

add_custom_command( OUTPUT Dockerfile.base
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D DISTRO_NAME=${DISTRO_NAME} -D DISTRO_VERSION=${DISTRO_VERSION} -D PROJECT_TEMPLATE_DIR=${PROJECT_TEMPLATE_DIR} -P ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/ConfigureDockerfileBase.cmake
        COMMENT "Configure the Dockerfile.base file."
    )

Comment: What if I want to implement such logic: execute that script only when a variable is defined ? How should I write this in `add_custom_target` ? @Adam

Comment: Works great when the function is in a `.cmake` file, is there an option to call a function defined on the same CMakeLists.txt file ? @Adam Kosiorek

Comment: How to return values from that script ?

Comment: @Ragul [How to set the global variable in a function for cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10031953/12447766)