# CMake: Set up Multiple Projects and Dependencies Between Them

Tags: c++, cmake, multiple-projects

I need help with writing good `CMakeLists.txt` files for `C++` projects.

This is the structure of my projects:

```
MainProj
|  ProjLib/
|  |  include/
|  |  |  proj_lib.h
|  |  src/
|  |  |  proj_lib.cc
|  |  CMakeLists.txt
|  ProjExec/
|  |  include/
|  |  |  proj_exec.h
|  |  src/
|  |  |  proj_exec.cc
|  |  CMakeLists.txt
|  CMakeLists.txt
```

---

`MainProj` `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MainProj CXX)

# enable C and C++ language
enable_language(C CXX)

# Add sub-directories
add_subdirectory(ProjLib)
add_subdirectory(ProjExec)
```

---

`ProjLib` `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set (PROJLIB_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
 
set(PROJLIB_SRCS 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/proj_lib.cc
)
 
include_directories("${PROJLIB_SOURCE_DIR}")
include_directories("${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}")
 
add_library(ProjLib SHARED ${PROJLIB_SRCS} ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_include_directories (ProjLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

---

`ProjExec` `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (PROJEXEC_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set (PROJEXEC_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(PROJEXEC_SRCS 
    ${PROJEXEC_SOURCE_DIR}/proj_exec.cc
)
 
include_directories("${PROJEXEC_SOURCE_DIR}")
include_directories("${PROJEXEC_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable(ProjExec ${PROJEXEC_SRCS})

target_link_libraries (ProjExec LINK_PUBLIC ProjLib)
```

---

`proj_exec.cc`:

```
#include "proj_lib.h"
...
```

And it doesn't found `proj_lib.h` in `proj_exec.cc` file.
Do I need some additional entries in some `cmake`?

Comment: In `ProjExec/CMakeLists.txt` you include directories `ProjExec/src` and `ProjExec/include`. Your library target carries include directory (added with `target_include_directories`) `ProjLib`, which is propagated to executable. But none of these directories is equal to `ProjLib/include` where header `proj_lib.h` is located. So, why do you expect that the header should be found?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to make use of the CMake targets and their properties:

MainProj/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MainProj)

# Add sub-directories
add_subdirectory(ProjLib)
add_subdirectory(ProjExec)
```

ProjLib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(ProjLib SHARED src/proj_lib.cc)
target_include_directories(ProjLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
```

ProjExec/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(ProjExec src/proj_exec.cc)
target_include_directories(ProjExec PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(ProjExec ProjLib)
```

`target_link_libraries` makes sure that when building a target, its dependencies' PUBLIC and INTERFACE include directories will be used appropriately.

Comment: Interesting: so OP just needs to change `include_directories("${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}")` into `target_include_directories (ProjLib PUBLIC ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})` in ProjLib's CMakeLists.txt? Where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: @Antonio: the [page on `target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html?highlight=target_include_directories) talks about `PUBLIC` populating [the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES), which is used when you call `target_link_libraries`: "When target dependencies are specified using target_link_libraries(), CMake will read this property from all target dependencies to determine the build properties of the consumer."

Comment: In short, if you're not using these features, you're doing it wrong. There are still some IMHO stupid limitations in very useful corner cases, but I still think CMake does the best job even though their syntax is abysmal.

Comment: Thanks, it was really well hidden! Indeed, it is the best way of doing this!

Comment: I have added an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40244458/2436175).

Comment: Thanks! I really had a problem with understanding all of this cmake stuff... :) Now, it's quite clear.

Comment: @rubenvb : However I have another question : If there in ProjExec/CMakeLists.txt shouldn't be  `target_include_directories(ProjExec PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)`

Comment: @BartekPL Might be. I didn't test the above code. I changed it in the answer because your suggestion has less chance of being wrong ;).

Answer (score 1):

Your cmake project template looks fine and self-contained. First, I'm going to assume `GAITPARAMS_SRCS` was supposed to be `PROJEXEC_SRCS` which is currently pointing at proj_exec.cc contains a main() method. (If you're going to manage a SRCS list, be careful not to add source files at the top of the list, add_executable expects the main function to be in the first entry)

Secondly, the problem is in your `ProjLib/CMakeLists.txt`. Try replacing your `target_include_directories` call with this:

```
target_include_directories (ProjLib PUBLIC ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

This will propagate the include directory information to the ProjExec when the `target_link_libraries` command is applied. If you don't wan't to do that, I guess you can access via `#include <include/ProjLib.h>` but that's just confusing. My recommendation is to add another folder in the include folder (named exactly the same with the cmake folder) and add your headers in it. Like this:

```
MainProj
|  ProjLib/
|  |  include/
|  |  |  ProjLib/
|  |  |  |  proj_lib.h
|  |  src/
|  |  |  proj_lib.cc
|  |  CMakeLists.txt
```

This lets you include your headers with a foldername (Not to mention preventing name collision.). Like this:

```
#include <ProjLib/proj_lib.h>
```

And to configure your CMakeLists.txt files to match the pattern.

Comment: It is failing because it can not find the header files of ProjLib. It can not find ProjLib headers because ProjLib didn't configure it's include directory path correctly. 
I have created the folder structure and tested it. You can also try it yourself, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I suggest you read through my answer. I have given the solution and THEN my recommendations. Like I said, try it yourself.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. I suggest you look into target_include_directories documentation here. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html . It acts here, as a tip for other targets who are linking ProjLib into them, and make the include statements, without ProjExec knowing what to include. So, It is ProjLib's problem. It's not compilation of ProjLib thats the issue. It's not properly configured to aid future targets to include it's headers. That's the purpose of that function. I ,once again, advise you to try it up.

Comment: I sort of get now what you meant. This answer could be much clearer if you rephrased You're trying to include the directory itself (where exactly?), cmake has no way of resolving where to link to (are we speaking about linking or including?).

Comment: Yes, good point with PROJEXEC_SRCS :) It was mistake. Edited :) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BartekPL Could you accept this as an answer? Downvoters are welcome to comment.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't possibility to do that before. You're answer is good, but rubenvb explained everything better. However +1 ☺

Answer (score 0):

All of the following are valid, but the best option is explained in [rubenvb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242257/2436175).

---

You have at least 3 options:

1) Add the following line in ProjExec/CMakeLists.txt:

```
 target_include_directories (ProjExec PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjLib/include)
```

2) You can extend the visibility of the variable `PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR`, by adding the `CACHE INTERNAL` keywords

```
 set(PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

and then use it in ProjExec/CMakeLists.txt:

```
 target_include_directories (ProjExec PUBLIC ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

See [How to set the global variable in a function for cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031953/how-to-set-the-global-variable-in-a-function-for-cmake)
Of course ProjLib must come first in the `add_subdirectory` sequence in the main CMakeLists.txt file.

3) I couldn't test this one. If you in ProjLib's CMakeLists.txt use this line:

```
 target_include_directories (ProjLib PUBLIC ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Then in ProjExec's CMakeLists.txt you can extract the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, and use it:

```
 get_target_property(ProjLib PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) #Do not use anymore CACHE INTERNAL (Point 2)
 target_include_directories (ProjExec PUBLIC ${PROJLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}) #or PRIVATE
```

These 2 lines can be compacted in one, using [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)) (untested):

```
target_include_directories (ProjExec PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:ProjLib,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>) #or PRIVATE
```

See also [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) and [get_target_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html).

---

Other notes:

- Either use `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`, not both.
- You normally wouldn't need to have the source directory as include directory, i.e. you can remove `include_directories("${PROJLIB_SOURCE_DIR}")` and `include_directories("${PROJEXEC_SOURCE_DIR}")`

Comment: Thanks for all notes :) It is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the properties of a target, a key point is to comprehend the command of `target_include_directories` and its keywords of `PRIVATE`, `INTERFACE`, and `PUBLIC`.
`PRIVATE` indicates that the include directory is only needed by the target.
`INTERFACE` indicates that the include directory is needed when other targets would like to link this target, and `cmake` will deal with it automatically.
`PUBLIC` means both this target and other targets which depend on it have to compass this directory into its search path.
All of this is determined by your code.