# CMake: pass library name to grandparent, but only if grandparent exists

Tags: cmake, scoping

A library `foo` is to be built either as a project of its own, or as part of a larger project `bar`. For the latter, I found no better solution than line (*):

```
$ cat foo/lib/CMakeLists.txt
...
set(foo_LIBRARY foo PARENT_SCOPE)
...

$ cat foo/CMakeLists.txt
...
add_subdirectory(lib)
set(cerf_LIBRARY ${cerf_LIBRARY} PARENT_SCOPE)  # (*)
...

$ cat bar/CMakeLists.txt
...
add_subdirectory(link-to-foo)
...
```

Now building `bar` works. But when building only `foo`, I get

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:30 (set):
  Cannot set "foo_LIBRARY": current scope has no parent.
```

Aiming for zero warnings in my projects, I'd need a better solution.

Comment: Not sure why you say about "grandparent", but for check whether *parent* exists see e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199677/how-to-detect-if-current-scope-has-a-parent-in-cmake.

Comment: Indeed, that could be used to solve my problem, thank you. But shouldn't be there a simpler solution, e.g. by making `foo_LIBRARY` known at global scope?

Comment: "... making foo_LIBRARY known at global scope" - Just create CACHE variable: `set(foo_LIBRARY <...> CACHE INTERNAL "")`. After that, the variable can be dereferenced in any time. BTW, there is a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031953/how-to-set-the-global-variable-in-a-function-for-cmake.

Comment: Which was not in the accepted answer. Which I therefore edited. Would be nice if you could check.